# Service started by AlarmManager gets restarted with null intent after application removed from apps tray

Tags: android, android-service, scheduled-tasks, android-pendingintent

I'm beginner android programmer. While experimenting with background Services and background data download I came across this particular problem:

I'm using an AlarmManager to schedule repeating background data download.

```
public void setBackgroundDataService(Context context, long time_in_millis) {

    Intent background_service_intent = new Intent(context, BackgroundDataService.class);
    background_service_intent.putExtra("value", val);
    PendingIntent pending_intent = PendingIntent.getService(context, BACKGROUND_DATA_SERVICE_ID , background_service_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    cancelBackgroundServiceAlarmIfExists(context, background_service_intent);

    AlarmManager alarm_manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm_manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, (System.currentTimeMillis() + time_in_millis), time_in_millis, pending_intent);
}


public static void cancelBackgroundServiceAlarmIfExists(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // try to cancel Pending Intent if exists
    try {
        PendingIntent pending_intent = PendingIntent.getService(context, BACKGROUND_DATA_SERVICE_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarm_manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm_manager.cancel(pending_intent);
        Log.d("DEBUG", "Background service terminated");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is onStartCommand() from Service:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    Log.d("DEBUG", "Background service invoked");

    if (intent == null)
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

    some_value = extras.getString("value");

    startDataDownload();

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Data download is performed in AsyncTask

So the problem is:
Why after swiping the app from applications tray Service gets restarted and intent passed in arguments is null. Proper working of the Service relies on extras passed in the intent. At first my application would just crash (usually 2 times, I assume that something was trying to restart it, but crashed while trying to get extras from null intent). After some time Service would start properly and do its job without crashing (probably AlarmManager restarted it with proper intent extras after specified time). Then sporadically it would crash again. I managed to avoid crashes by checking whether intent is null or not. It seems to work. But the question remains.

> Why is my Service getting restarted and null intent gets passed to it right after I swipe my app from application tray. Is there anything thet can be done about it? Is there a better way to download data periodically?

Answer (score 0):

In `onStartCommand()` you are returning `START_STICKY` because of this:

```
return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
```

`START_STICKY` tells Android that it should restart your `Service` if the `Service` is killed (for whatever reason). When you swipe your app from the list of recent tasks, Android kills the OS process hosting your app and then, because your `Service` returned `START_STICKY`, Android restarts your `Service`.

After restarting your `Service`, Android calls `onStartCommand()` with a null `Intent` parameter.

It looks like you are also not stopping your `Service` after the data download completes.

If you only want your `Service` to be restarted if it is killed while it is working on something, return `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` from `onStartCommand()`.

The [documentation for `Service`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) explains this:

> For started services, there are two additional major modes of
>   operation they can decide to run in, depending on the value they
>   return from onStartCommand(): START_STICKY is used for services that
>   are explicitly started and stopped as needed, while START_NOT_STICKY
>   or START_REDELIVER_INTENT are used for services that should only
>   remain running while processing any commands sent to them.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this kind of problem recently. So what I did is make my service looks like a foreground task and that'll solve your problem. And to do that the best approach I can think of is using a notification. [Here is the required documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)). And here is a sample code for the notification -

```
 private void showNotification() {
    String notificationTitle = "Notification Title";
    String notificationContent = "Notification Content";

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)
            .setTicker(AppConstants.App_Name)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setColor(getApplicationContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite))
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(notificationContent))
            .setAutoCancel(false)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);
}
```

If you like to stop this process just call `void stopForeground (int flags)` where ever you like. It won't kill your service but your process will no longer be a foreground task.